# Numbering of Lemmas in Appendix

Tags: numbering, theorems, appendices

I'm preparing a paper using the Lipics style and have a long appendix: each appendix Section is headed by capital letters A,B,C... I would like to have the numbering of Lemmas in the appendix such as Lemma A.1 (if it is in appendix A), resp. Lemma B.1, B.2,... (in appendix B) etc. Any hint? I tried to redefine the \thetheorem variable and played with it for a while, but was not succesful, I'm not very strong at LaTeX.

Thanks for possible hint! Here is a minimal working code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, USenglish, numberwithinsect]{lipics}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{observation}[theorem]{Observation}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}

\title{Title}
\author[1]{Peter Franek}
\affil[1]{Affil}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
abstract
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{s:intro}
\begin{theorem}
Theorem 1
\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}
First Lemma
\end{lemma}

\appendix
\section{first appendix chapter}
Some text..
\begin{lemma}
I don't want Lemma 1.1 but either Lemma A.1 or Lemma A.1.1
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: How should be the numbering before the appendix? Continous throughout the paper? Per section?

Comment: I will include a working example, give me a second.. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's easy with the `apptools` and `chngcntr` packages:

*Edit* (8/1/2020): `changcntr` is no more necessary since `\counterwithin` is now part of the LaTeX kernel.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,oneside]{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{apptools}
\AtAppendix{\counterwithin{lemma}{section}}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}
\section{A First Section}

\begin{lemma}
A first lemma.
\end{lemma}

\appendix
\section{An appendix section}

\begin{lemma}
A lemma in appendix.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: For answers that achieve this without the use of special packages see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573078/adding-letters-to-theorem-labels-to-specify-the-theorem-is-in-the-appendix-with.