# Lemma numbering not changed in appendix when using a solution

Tags: numbering, appendices, amsthm, appendix, lemma

I am trying to implement the lemma numbering solution in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215886/numbering-of-lemmas-in-appendix). I am currently compiling the document from a parent file such that:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{apptools}
\AtAppendix{\counterwithin{lemma}{section}}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{appendices}
\include{Appendix1/appendix1}
\end{appendices}
```

where the appendix file has

```
\begin{lemma}
A lemma in appendix.
\end{lemma}
```

The lemma number remains sequential and doesn't change to reflect that it is in the appendix file...

Answer (score 0):

I added a line to this section of code

```
\begin{appendices}
\appendix
\include{Appendix1/appendix1}
\end{appendices}
```

Not sure if this is the correct solution, but it works.